# How to change the input source to different language with shortcut (only one key combination)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, language, shortcut

I want to use four language in my OS X system (English, Spanish, Chinese, and Japanese), and I know I can change the language with `⌘` + `Space`. However, I have a pathological hatred for switching with it, because it requires me to select from so, so many choices! I also know I can change it from the menubar on the right of the bar, but it's much more disgusting than the `⌘` + `Space` solution.

So I rather want to change it with easier shortcut, like the following:

- left `⌘` switches to English
- right `⌘` switches to Spanish
- left `⌘` + left `⌥` + `C` switches to Chinese
- right `⌘` + right `⌥` + `C` switches to Japanese.

I tried to use `Karabiner` (the descendent from `KeyRemap4MacBook`), but it doesn't work on the first attempt on Chinese, on which when I switches to Chinese, it remains English (the input source icon on the menubar changes, but the keyboard does not work). But for some reasons if I switch from English to Chinese to English to Chinese (two attempts), then the Chinese keyboard finally works.

So I don't like the idea of using `Karabiner`. So what is the better way to change the input source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with Chinese and Japanese. (The icon on the menu bar changed but the input source was not actually changed until I switched to another input source and back.) It's a known bug according to [a post at Karabiner's mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/osx-karabiner/vkchangeinputsourcedef/osx-karabiner/w4HF8OGBjR4/ZdyjoUN5IV8J):

> It's one of the most annoying bug of OS X.
>
> Changing CJK input sources directly from program is not handled appropriately.
>
> So, you need the following procedures.
>
> Step1:
>   Enable "Select next source in Input menu" (command-option-space) on System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts.
>
> Step2:
>   Change input source by sending command-option-space.
>
> ```
> <autogen>
>   __KeyToKey__
>   KeyCode::K, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
>   KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTMODE_US,
>   KeyCode::VK_WAIT_100MS,
>   KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
>   <!-- adjust wait for your machine -->
>   KeyCode::VK_WAIT_10MS,
>   KeyCode::VK_WAIT_10MS,
>   KeyCode::VK_WAIT_10MS,
>   KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
>   <!-- adjust wait for your machine -->
>   KeyCode::VK_WAIT_10MS,
>   KeyCode::VK_WAIT_10MS,
>   KeyCode::VK_WAIT_10MS,
>   KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R | ModifierFlag::OPTION_L,
>
>   Option::NOREPEAT,
> </autogen>
> ```

[changeinput](https://gist.github.com/amitu/2146751) is affected by the same bug.

Another workaround is to just change to another input source and back:

```
<root>
  <vkchangeinputsourcedef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_HIRAGANA</name>
    <inputsourceid_equal>com.apple.inputmethod.Kotoeri.Japanese</inputsourceid_equal>
  </vkchangeinputsourcedef>
  <vkchangeinputsourcedef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_SPANISH</name>
    <inputsourceid_equal>com.apple.keylayout.Spanish</inputsourceid_equal>
  </vkchangeinputsourcedef>
  <vkchangeinputsourcedef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_US</name>
    <inputsourceid_equal>com.apple.keylayout.US</inputsourceid_equal>
  </vkchangeinputsourcedef>
  <vkchangeinputsourcedef>
    <name>KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_CHINESE</name>
    <inputsourceid_equal>com.apple.inputmethod.TCIM.Pinyin</inputsourceid_equal>
  </vkchangeinputsourcedef>
  <item>
    <name>inputsources</name>
    <identifier>inputsources</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::COMMAND_L, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_US, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_SPANISH, KeyCode::COMMAND_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_CHINESE, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_US, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_CHINESE</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::C, ModifierFlag::OPTION_R | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_R | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_HIRAGANA, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_US, KeyCode::VK_CHANGE_INPUTSOURCE_HIRAGANA</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: Your second solution disables the command key for all the other shortcuts (like `⌘`+`W` to close the window), which is definitely not what I want... As to the 1st solution, I'll try it later.

Comment: As to your first solution, I'm not sure why you want to wait 160ms and switch it three times...

Comment: Hmmm... I still have issues in the `__KeyOverlaidModifier__` as noted above, but I switched Japanese and Spanish inputsource because Japanese inputsource can function properly if you set it from within Karabiner's preferences in the Japanese inputsource section. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>  is a "dead" key, a modifier key. It does nothing on its own, though as it keeps a count of how many times it's pressed, that would be possibly why it's working at the second attempt.

More to the point... why would you want to use  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  to switch input language,  thereby eliminating its use for any other function.

Why not use F-Keys, perhaps, instead?

A better solution might be one of these...

https://superuser.com/questions/224161/switch-to-specific-input-source

Comment: I don't stick to using the apple key. (maybe you might have mistaken `⌘`(command key) with the apple key...?)

Comment: Well, it's because `⌘` is the easiest to type, and switching between different languages occur so, so frequently.

Comment: my point still stands.

Answer (score 0):

check this

switch with simple press left_shift -> us, right_shift->ua

```
"rules": [
                    {
                        "description": "Right Shift to UA",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "right_shift",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "optional": [
                                            "any"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "right_shift",
                                        "lazy": true
                                    }
                                ],
                                "to_if_alone": [
                                    {
                                        "select_input_source": {
                                            "language": "uk"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "description": "Right Shift to US",
                        "manipulators": [
                            {
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "left_shift",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "optional": [
                                            "any"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "left_shift",
                                        "lazy": true
                                    }
                                ],
                                "to_if_alone": [
                                    {
                                        "select_input_source": {
                                            "language": "en"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```